# Как сделать insert, состоящий частично из результата select?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с 4-мя полями.

Из SELECT я получаю 2 поля для вставки, а остальные два мне надо заполнить одними и теми же данными. Примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3, f4)

   SELECT f1, f2 FROM other_table        -- f1 и f2 взять из SELECT

   SET f3 = 'value_1', f4 = 'value_2'    -- f3 и f4 я добавлю сам
```

Можно, конечно, в SELECT добавить `'value_1' AS f3`, `'value_2' AS f4`, но получается как-то костыльно.

Можно как-то изящнее и прозрачнее сделать такой запрос?

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO table(f1, f2, f3, f4)

SELECT f1, f2, 2, 3 FROM other_table ? //f3 =2, f4 = 3
```